# How do I use typeof with dynamic types?

Tags: c

I'm slightly confused about typeof and how to use it properly. I know typedefs exist but I imagine typedefs are more for static/compile time types where as typeof is dynamic?

In this code

```
int main()
{
    int t[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    typeof(t) a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since t is an array allocated on the stack is then typeof(t) a also an array allocated on the stack?
Or what if I made a pointer point to t, then made a type of p ?

```
int main()
{
    int t[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int* p = t;
    typeof(p) a;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is a now just an integer pointer that hasn't been allocated?

Or if I allocate t dynamically then make a typeof t

```
int main()
{
    int* t = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        t[i] = i;
    }
    typeof(t) a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        a[i] = i;//crashes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this again just an integer pointer and allocation does not play a role?

Or what if I wanted to take a pointer but make a 2d array out of that pointer?

```
int main()
{
    int* t = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        t[i] = i;
    }
    typeof(t) a[2][3];
    printf("%d\n",a[0][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is that valid?

```
int main()
{

    
    int x  = 2;
    int y = 3;
    typeof(int[x][y]) a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            a[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or is that valid? Is a already allocated on the stack here ? If it is, then is it using VLA to do a stack based allocation for the array?
Am I just over thinking what typeof does?

Comment: `typeof` is static, not dynamic. And it isn't standard C. Its main use is for macros where you don't already know the types.

Comment: `c` is statically typed, which means all types are resolved at compile-time. `typeof` is a compiler extension, and not something built into the language.

Comment: The reason I ask is because from what I just read, typeof became standard in C23

Comment: @interjay So typeof is more for type validation than decleration?

Comment: It can be used to declare things in a macro with the same type as a parameter. I don't know what you mean by type validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` is a **gcc** extension used mainly for macros.

All types in C are known to the compiler at compile time, avoid using `typeof()` in source code as it makes the code less readable and the type should be easy to find. `typeof` is not a C equivalent of the `auto` keyword used in C++ to let the compiler infer the type from the context. `auto` is a reserved keyword in C to specify automatic storage, which is implicit for local objects, hence the keyword is never used.

Here is an example of a macro that uses the `typeof` extension:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(x, y) do { typeof(x) *x__ = &(x), *y__ = &(y), t__ = *x__; \
                        *x__ = *y__; *y__ = t__; } while (0)

int main() {
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 2;
    unsigned u1 = 1, u2 = 2;
    long l1 = 1, l2 = 2;
    double d1 = 1, d2 = 2;
    const char *str1 = "1", *str2 = "2";
    struct { int x; } s1 = { 1 }, s2 = { 2 };
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3 }, a2[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    SWAP(i1, i2);
    SWAP(u1, u2);
    SWAP(l1, l2);
    SWAP(d1, d2);
    SWAP(str1, str2);
    SWAP(s1, s2);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 3;) {
        SWAP(a1[i++], a2[j++]);
    }
    printf("i1 = %d, i2 = %d\n", i1, i2);
    printf("u1 = %u, u2 = %u\n", u1, u2);
    printf("l1 = %ld, l2 = %ld\n", l1, l2);
    printf("d1 = %g, d2 = %g\n", d1, d2);
    printf("str1 = %s, str2 = %s\n", str1, str2);
    printf("s1 = { %d }, s2 = { %d }\n", s1.x, s2.x);
    printf("a1 = { %d, %d, %d }, a2 = { %d, %d, %d }\n",
           a1[0], a1[1], a1[2], a2[0], a2[1], a2[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i1 = 2, i2 = 1
u1 = 2, u2 = 1
l1 = 2, l2 = 1
d1 = 2, d2 = 1
str1 = 2, str2 = 1
s1 = { 2 }, s2 = { 1 }
a1 = { 4, 5, 6 }, a2 = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Note however that the `SWAP` macro can be defined in Standard C with the same semantics as:

```
#include <string.h>

#define SWAP(x, y) do { void *x__ = &(x), *y__ = &(y); \
                        size_t s__ = sizeof(x);        \
                        unsigned char t__[s__];        \
                        memcpy(t__, x__, s__);         \
                        memcpy(x__, y__, s__);         \
                        memcpy(y__, t__, s__);         \
                   } while (0)
```

Comment: But typeof is faster since you don't have to rely on memcpy?

Comment: `typeof` is not standard yet (as of Feb 2022), and even if it becomes part of C23, it won't be widely available for decades as C compiler vendors are notoriously slow to pickup.  Furthermore it might not even be faster in the above example as `memcpy` is usually handled as a builtin by optimizing compilers that will generate the same code for both versions.

Comment: In the argument to including `typeof` in the next C standard, it was stated that every compiler basically already has it implemented behind the scenes in order to implement the `sizeof` operator, so I imagine it would likely be one of the first things made available by compilers as they begin exposing experimental support for the standard. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2685.htm#implementation-existing-practice  Also, as an aside, I believe your variable names in the macro invoke undefined behavior as identifiers beginning with two underscores are reserved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "dynamic type" in C. Types are fully resolved in the compiler and then cease to exist. `typeof` is substituted as though it were a `typedef` for the declared type of its argument, which doesn't have to be a simple variable.

In your fourth example:

```
int main()
{
    int* t = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        t[i] = i;
    }
    typeof(t) a[2][3];
    printf("%d\n",a[0][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

`typeof(t)` is precisely `int*` because that's what you declared `t` to be. So the new variable `a` has type `int* [2][3]` -- that is, an array of arrays of pointers to `int`. That's probably not what you want, since you try to print one of its (uninitialised) elements as though it were an integer. That suggest that the declaration you were looking for was:

```
    typeof(*t) a[2][3];
```

In any event, how a variable is allocated and what its type is are two orthogonal concepts (although certain restrictions apply, notably that you cannot declare a VLA at global scope).

As another take-away, *always enable compiler warnings*. I suspect that reading the error messages would have helped with at least some of those examples.

Comment: So I guess what's confusing me is why does typeof even exist? What's the point of it if we have typedef

Comment: @yuumi it's mostly useful for writing macros.

Comment: I see. Is it mainly just to check what type a variable is rather than declaring a variable?

Comment: @Yuumi: There is a motivating example in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.3.0/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) where they show the definition of a `max` macro which doesn't evaluate its arguments twice. (So `max(a++,b)` works.) The example depends on another GCC extension, expression blocks.

Comment: There is very little you can use a type for in C other than to declare a variable. (Although now that the language has `_Generic`, there are some possible uses of `typeof` for matching, I don't think they're very common.) The example I cited in the previous comment is the most likely use.

Comment: Actually C support types partially defined in runtime called Variable Modified Types (i.e. `typedef int T[n];`. They are used to handle VLA objects.

Comment: @tstanisl: I guess that's a semantic discussion which is probably not very fruitful. Two VMTs are compatible if their base types are compatible.  You can't use a VMT in a _Generic. If you pass a (pointer to) a VMT to a function, the size of the VMT does not accompany the argument; the parameter has its own type; compatibility is checked at compile-time and there is no defined run-time check. So the compiler can fully erase the type, as with any other type; it only has to substitute `sizeof` (if it occurs) with some internal variable.